# I can use dynamic find_by_* methods in rails, such as Company.find_by_name_and_zip_and_phone, but how can we use a multipart property in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can use dynamic find_by_* methods in rails, such as `Company.find_by_name_and_zip_and_phone`, but how can we use a multipart property in it? Such as the **update_at** property, when I try to use `Company.find_by_name_and_zip_and_phone_and_update_at`, i got an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_state_and_name_and_phone_and_update_at' for #<Class:0x45769e0>
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work fine except I think you mean updated_at.